# Displaying repleatable meta box

Tags: wordpress

i found this  code and trying to display it. But i can't figure out how to. Anyone who can help ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: this code https://gist.github.com/da1nonly/2253622

Comment: Did you added the code to the functions.php file in your theme.